# Why does `variable++` increment the variable but `variable + 1` does not?

Tags: kotlin

Here's the problem in which I encountered this issue:

The function should compare the value at each index position and score a point if the value for that position is higher. No point if they are the same. Given `a = [1, 1, 1] b = [1, 0, 0]` output should be `[2, 0]`

```
fun compareArrays(a: Array<Int>, b: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {

    var aRetVal:Int = 0
    var bRetVal:Int = 0

    for(i in 0..2){
        when {
            a[i] > b[i] -> aRetVal + 1 // This does not add 1 to the variable
            b[i] > a[i] -> bRetVal++ // This does...
        }
    }
    return arrayOf(aRetVal, bRetVal)

}
```

The IDE even says that aRetVal is unmodified and should be declared as a `val`

Comment: Why do you expect `aRetVal` to change? The way you have it, the result of `aRetVal + 1` is not assigned to a variable. It is popular in many languages (see C++, Java, PHP, JavaScript, etc) that `varName++` implicitly assigns to itself. See the [increment/decrement operators documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements) and the [arithmetic operators documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What others said is true, but in Kotlin there's more. `++` is just syntactic sugar and under the hood it will call `inc()` on that variable. The same applies to `--`, which causes `dec()` to be invoked (see [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements)). In other words `a++` is equivalent to `a.inc()` (for `Int` or other primitive types that gets optimised by the compiler and increment happens without any method call) followed by a reassignment of `a` to the incremented value.

As a bonus, consider the following code:

```
fun main() {
    var i = 0
    val x = when {
        i < 5 -> i++
        else -> -1
    }

    println(x) // prints 0
    println(i) // prints 1

    val y = when {
        i < 5 -> ++i
        else -> -1
    }

    println(y) // prints 2
    println(i) // prints 2 
}
```

The explanation for that comes from the documentation I linked above:

> The compiler performs the following steps for resolution of an operator in the *postfix* form, e.g. `a++`:

- Store the initial value of a to a temporary storage a0;
- Assign the result of a.inc() to a;
- Return a0 as a result of the expression.

> ...
>
> For the prefix forms `++a` and `--a` resolution works the same way, and the effect is:
>
> - Assign the result of a.inc() to a;
> - Return the new value of a as a result of the expression.

Comment: For ```a++```, I get the new value assigned to a. For ```a.inc``` I don't get the new value assigned to a. In fact I can do a.inc(), also when a is a 'val' (immutable). So I would suggest that a++ and a.inc() is not equivalent.

Comment: @TorbjörnÖsterdahl that's right. What I meant is that `a++` calls `a.inc()` under the hood, but it's true that the former implies the resulting value is reassigned to `a` in the end. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

Because

`variable++` is shortcut for `variable = variable + 1` (i.e. with assignment)

and

`variable + 1` is "shortcut" for `variable + 1` (i.e. without assignment, and actually not a shortcut at all).

Answer (score 2):

That is because what notation `a++` does is actually `a=a+1`, not just `a+1`. As you can see, `a+1` will return a value that is bigger by one than `a`, but not overwrite `a` itself.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to `a++` is `a = a + 1`, you have to do a reassignment which the inc operator does as well.

This is not related to Kotlin but a thing you'll find in pretty much any other language